# if else statement dateframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements, mean

I have a dataframe (df):

```
df<- Column1  Column2 Column3
```

I want to do an ifelse statement with the mean of the values of Column2 and call including two other dataframes (df2 and df3) in my statement.

Here is the formula I used:

```
ifelse(mean(df$Column2)<5,df2,df3)
```

It does not produce df2 or df3 as a dataframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What language is this written in?

Comment: Nevermind I just figure it out. It was in R. Here is what I did: CONDITIONAL<-function(x)
{
if(x<5)
{
print(eCPM2)
}
else
{
print(eCPMLOGIC)
}
}
CONDITIONAL(averagecpm)

Comment: You might want to post that as the answer then ;-)  P.S. I formatted your question and retagged it

Comment: @Nick Knauer, `ifelse` is a vectorized operation.  Generally, you pass it vectors of length greater than 1.  The mean of a data frame, is a vector of length 1 (i.e. a scalar, but there are no scalar's in R).  Consequently, as you note in your comment, you need to use `if{}else{}`

Answer (score 0):

From the "stupid but works" department:

```
get(ifelse(mean(df$Column2)<5,"df2","df3"))
```